# Password change in AWS - alarm via CloudWatch or CloudTrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

I ws surprised to see an example of a password change in AWS being shown as being part of AWS CloudWatch. I would have thought this was a thing for CloudTrail.

What am I missing here? Can it be in both?

Comment: Can you post the example event?

Comment: At the bottome of this blog. @jellycsc

Comment: Where is the blog?

Comment: https://tomgregory.com/aws-sns-for-cloudwatch-alarm-email-notifications/ @jellycsc

Comment: You probably confuse the Linux password and the password of the AWS management console. The blog is about how to trigger a CW alarm when a password change in Linux is detected.

Comment: @jellycsc  Ah right. So it must go thru CloudWatch indeed. You may want to write an answer here. Fooled!!!

Comment: :) I'm glad that I can help you clear the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A password change in the Linux operating system is totally different from changing your password of the AWS management console. Details are in the comment section.